# Scanner wrapping strings in braces

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a method which processes a line to seperate the first word which it puts into a string called cmd and the rest which it enters into a vector of strings for the parameters and then sends them to a function to process the command. The parameters are getting wrapped in square braces for some reason.

```
static private boolean processLine(String line) {
            if (debug) System.out.println("DEBUG: processLine \"" + line + "\"");    

            line = new String(line.trim());
            String cmd = new String();
            Vector<String> params = new Vector<String>(3);
            boolean hasparam = false;
            Scanner s = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter(" ");
            int x = 0;
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                    if (x == 0) { cmd = s.next(); }
                    else if (x >= 1) {
                            params.add(s.next());
                            hasparam = true;
                    }
                    x++;
            }

            // Next we process the command.
            processCmd(cmd, params);

            return exit;
    }

static private void processCmd(String cmd, Vector<String> params) {
            boolean invalid = false;

            if (debug) {
                    System.out.print("DEBUG: processCmd " + cmd);
                    if (params.size() == 0) System.out.println();
                    else for (String param : params) 
                           System.out.println(" " + params);
            }
```

Output:

```
> add hosting
DEBUG: processLine "add hosting"
DEBUG: processCmd add [hosting]
```

I'm not sure why I am getting this behaviour, and I would like an explanation as well as a solution.

Answer (score 3):

> The parameters are getting wrapped in square braces for some reason.

This is because you are printing the `Vector` itself rather than the element of `Vector`. So `toString()` method of `Vector` is calling out in following line:

```
System.out.println(" " + params);
```

Change this line to:

```
System.out.println(" " + param);
```

Comment: Indeed. If there were multiple parameters, the bug would have been obvious: `> add hosting 1` would produce `DEBUG: processCmd add [hosting, 1] [hosting, 1]`.

Comment: @MichaelMyers: No , in this case `params` has only only element and that element is `hosting`.

Comment: Thanks. The little things we can miss.

Comment: @VishalK: Right; that's why the OP thought his code was working aside from the `[]`. If there were multiple parameters, the bug would have been obvious.